# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : jrebel.jar

Tags: linux, jboss, filepath, jrebel

When configuring JRebel on my remote server (JBoss on linux) I have configured the JVM arg as

> -javaagent:/home/user/jrebel.jar" -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true

The jrebel.jar is absolutely definitely in that location, yet the server fails to start with the error:

> Error opening zip
>   file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/jrebel.jar Error occurred
>   during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument

So the arg is oviously being passed to the JVM correctly, but for the life of me I can't work out why it can't find the jar. I've been through every Zero Turnaround article I can find + looked at the solutions that have resolved it for other people, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: `-javaagent:/home/user/jrebel.jar"` - is the " typo or do you actually have it like this? It could be causing the error.

Comment: Yes that's just a typo sorry

Comment: please add the java agent like "-javaagent:H:/xrebel/xrebel.jar " in arguments in the server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turned out to be a permissions problem - the JBoss user didn't have the permissions to access the directory that I had placed jrebel.jar into.

Would have been nice to have a more meaningfull error - e.g. 'permissions denied'. Shows my lack of Linux knowledge though I guess.

After the jar was moved to a directory within the JBoss installation + the jar owner was changed to the JBoss user and Read/Write/Execute permissions added, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , the permission is the reason that this error happens to me when I tried to open **PHPSTORM** and that error was :

*Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ${JetbrainsIdesCrackPath}
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument*

so before running **PHPSTORM** I had to run the command : `sudo -i` to get the root permission to run the program.